# How to programmatically enter edit mode of an item in a TListView?

Tags: delphi, listview

In the `TListView` control, you can edit an item by clicking on it twice. A box appears around the item for user to type in a new value. How can I enable edit mode programmatically? I would like to protect the list from accidental editing, and disable editing (by enabling the `ReadOnly` property). Then, when the user presses an `Edit` button, the item will become active to edit. How can I do this?

Also, if suppose the user selects an item, then scrolls out of that item's view, then presses `Edit`, the list needs to first scroll to make that item visible.

Comment: This is poor UI design. List views have a common and standard mechanism to allow editing. If you are really concerned about accidental edits doing damage, then let the user have an undo. I would also say that I have never made, nor ever witnessed such an accident. For the sake of something that never happens, you are inventing a clunky and non intuitive interface. That's a trade off where everyone loses.

Comment: It's not clicking an item twice. It's clicking on an item that's already selected. It's an important distinction to anyone who uses the keyboard. I'd suggest that rather than protect people by *disabling* a standard feature, you instead *add* another standard feature: undo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After setting `ReadOnly` to false you can call the [`EditCaption`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem.EditCaption) method. Call [`MakeVisible`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem.MakeVisible) to scroll the item in view.

```
ListView1.Items[0].MakeVisible(False);
ListView1.items[0].EditCaption;
```